# Display custom error message in login

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to implement a simple login with PHP. But, also  I want to customize the error message when the login is incorrect, for example display a error message in red color.

***Login.php***

```
<form id="frmlogin" name="frmlogin"  method="POST" action="validarUsuario.php">
    <p><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="required" maxlength="50" placeholder="Nombre Usuario"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required"  maxlength="50" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p id=error> </p>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
</form>
```

**validarUsuario.php**

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    conectar_bd();

    $usr = $_POST['usuario'];
    $pw = md5($_POST['password']);
    $sql = "SELECT usr FROM Client WHERE usr = '$usr'AND password ='$pw'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

    if ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        header('Location: menuclient.php');
    } else {
        /* How customize my message error */
    }
?>
```

In the `Login.php` file, when the username  or password are not correct, i want to display, for example, in *id=error* : "Login Incorrect" in red.
I dont know if I can do it with php. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sidenote: you should use a salt when you hash a password (https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: oh thanks! i will add  a salt to more security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `session`. Try following way.

Login.php

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSON['error']): ?>
    <span>Error : <?php echo $_SESSION['errorMsg']; ?></span>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <form id="frmlogin" name="frmlogin"  method="POST" action="validarUsuario.php">
            <p><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="required" maxlength="50" placeholder="Nombre Usuario"></p>
            <p><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required"  maxlength="50" placeholder="Password"></p>
             <p id=error> </p>
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
        </form>
```

validarUsuario.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include("connection.php");
conectar_bd();

$usr = $_POST['usuario'];
$pw = md5($_POST['password']);
$sql = "SELECT usr FROM Client WHERE usr = '$usr'AND password ='$pw'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);

if( $fila=mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
  header('Location: menuclient.php');
}
else {

  $_SESSION['errorMsg'] = "Wrong username or Password";
  $_SESSION['error'] = true;
  header('Location: Login.php');

}
?>
```

Comment: thanks!  I tested your code,but when I introduce a login incorrect , I am redirected to **Login.php** and the error isnt displayed.

Comment: This is the only way you can send your message to another page. Please check where session have set properly

Comment: very thanks! i found my little error. Your answer work.